# Different between multi_pragma vs shader_feature

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, cg

I go through a lot of documentation and google but still unclear. As state here, in unity doc,

### pragma_multi

```
#pragma multi_compile A B C
#pragma multi_compile D E
```

This would produce three variants for first line, and two for the second line, or in total six shader variants (A+D, B+D, C+D, A+E, B+E, C+E).

### shader_feature

pragma shader_feature is very similar to `#pragma multi_compile`, the only difference is that unused variants of `shader_feature` shaders will not be included into game build.

but for shader_feature i dont really understand.

What i try to achieve is my shader use specific function base on enum on script.
let say i have 2 function like below. I want only `One of them is use`.

```
fixed4 finalColor = fixed4(0,0,0,0);
#if FUNC
finalColor = Func(renderTex, newTex);
#endif  
#if OTHERFUNC
finalColor = OtherFunc(renderTex, newTex);
#endif
return finalColor;
```

My question is :

> 1. Is it possible to make enum in script that can choose only one of above(FUNC,OTHERFUNC), then shader will render base on that enum on runtime.
> 2. If possible, should i use `pragma_multi` or `shader_feature` ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to enable certain variants from your script, in fact that is why you have the multi_compile directive. You can edit your shader with:

```
#pragma multi_compile FUNC OTHERFUNC
```

or:

```
#pragma multi_compile __ OTHERFUNC
```

in order to stay safe from keyword limit (Unity has a limit on how many global keywords are in use at runtime). In this second case, the shader will be compiled with a variant where nothing is defined and another one which contains OTHERFUNC. If you're using this case, remove the FUNC test from your shader code and use just OTHERFUNC:

```
fixed4 finalColor = fixed4(0,0,0,0);
#if OTHERFUNC
finalColor = OtherFunc(renderTex, newTex);
#else
finalColor = Func(renderTex, newTex);
#endif  
return finalColor;
```

Then, in your script code, just can use something like:

```
material.EnableKeyword("OTHERFUNC");
```

to use the appropriate variant, where "material" is a variable pointing to your renderer material.

You can of course drive that keyword enable with an enum, if you want to match the name of the enum elements with the name of the shader feature names.

I hope this helps!